# Spring MVC and Mustache - change Mustache's compiler default null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mustache

I have some issues overriding default configuration of the Mustache for Spring MVC found [here](https://github.com/sps/mustache-spring-view/) in my project.

My understanding is that mustache.java raises a `MustacheException` by default when the template founds a variable that is resolved to be null. I would like for the Mustache compiler to resolve such values as an empty String instead.

I tried using the `nullValue(String nullValue)` function to set the appropriate behavior as seen in the code below, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I understand that the obvious solution is to set the `phoneNumber` attribute to an empty value, but I would really like to understand why this particular code doesn't work.

You'll find below the code I use to test this behavior, which includes an `Employee` entity that purposefully doesn't instantiate its `phoneNumber` member value in its constructor and the relevant code snippets.

Thanks in advance!

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.sps.mustache</groupId>
  <artifactId>mustache-spring-view</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- jmustache -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.samskivert</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmustache</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mustache.java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.17</version>
</dependency>
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
  protected String firstName;
  protected String lastName;
  protected String phoneNumber;

  public Employee() { }
  public Employee(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  // Getter and Setters for all attributes
}
```

**getViewResolver**

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
  MustacheViewResolver mustacheViewResolver = new MustacheViewResolver();
  mustacheViewResolver.setPrefix("/src/main/resources/templates/");
  mustacheViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
  mustacheViewResolver.setCache(false);
  mustacheViewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

  JMustacheTemplateLoader mustacheTemplateLoader = new JMustacheTemplateLoader();
  mustacheTemplateLoader.setResourceLoader(resourceLoader);

  JMustacheTemplateFactory mustacheTemplateFactory = new JMustacheTemplateFactory();
  mustacheTemplateFactory.setTemplateLoader(mustacheTemplateLoader);

  mustacheTemplateFactory.setCompiler(Mustache.compiler().nullValue(" "));

  mustacheViewResolver.setTemplateFactory(mustacheTemplateFactory);
  return mustacheViewResolver;
}
```

**EmployeeController**

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository repository;

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("employee", repository.findOne(id));
  return "employee_view";
}
```

**employee_view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <ul>
    {{#employee}}
    <li> First Name: {{firstName}}
    <li> Last Name: {{lastName}}
    <li> Phone Number: {{phoneNumber}}
    {{/employee}}
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using spring-boot.1.2.5.RELEASE now.

if you check out `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration` 's source code (line73 ~ 78), you call tell you `defaultValue` is unconfigable !!!

May be you should make a new your owne `spring-boot-starter` to fix it. 
Or you can use `freemarker` or `velocity` to instead it.

Or you can hack it by a `BeanPostProcessor` when ApplicationContext startup.

like this:

```
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor mutacheHackerBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        private static final String BEAN_NAME = "mustacheCompiler";

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (ClassUtils.isAssignable(bean.getClass(), Mustache.Compiler.class) || BEAN_NAME.equals(beanName)) {
                System.out.println("----------");
                System.out.println("hack ok!!!");
                System.out.println("----------");
                Mustache.Compiler compiler = (Mustache.Compiler) bean;
                return compiler.defaultValue("").nullValue("");
            }

            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that by creating custom Mustache auto configuration. First exclude default MustacheAutoConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MustacheAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then create new auto configuration for Mustache.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({MustacheProperties.class})
public class LayoutAutoConfiguration extends MustacheAutoConfiguration {

    public LayoutAutoConfiguration(MustacheProperties mustache, Environment environment, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(mustache, environment, applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Mustache.Compiler mustacheCompiler(Mustache.TemplateLoader mustacheTemplateLoader) {
        return super.mustacheCompiler(mustacheTemplateLoader).defaultValue("");
    }
}
```

Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE with jmustache 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
{{#employee}}
  <li> First Name: {{firstName}}
  <li> Last Name: {{lastName}}
  <li> Phone Number:{{#phoneNumber}} {{phoneNumber}} {{/phoneNumber}}     {{^phoneNumber}} NA {{/phoneNumber}}
{{/employee}}
</ul>
</body>
```